# Retrieve Booking Ticket

Tags: tickets, bookings

Why I can't retrieve my friend's ticket?  Even I've enter the correct number of confirmation code/ ticket code or even the first and the last name.  Is this a fake ticket?  Or maybe because of the special needs that mention in the top of the ticket and said "military verified"?

Comment: VTC as unclear. What kind of ticket are you even talking about?